# How to run ARM Assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm

I have learned ARM & Neon instruction set from reference manual. Now i want to use that in ARM processor,

```
void addArr(int *a,int *b){ int i=0;
 for(i=0;i<4;i++){
  a[i]=a[i]+b[i];
  } 
}
int main(){
 int a[4]={0,1,2,3};
 int b[4]={0,1,2,3};
 addArr(a,b);
 return 0;
}
```

for above function addArr(), i have written assembly code as

```
@by default r0- address of a, r1- address of b

 VLD1.I32 D0,D1,[R0]!        @loading 128 bit of input , i.e 4 element(32*4=128) of a
 VLD1.I32 D2,D3,[R1]!        @loading 128 bit of input , i.e 4 element(32*4=128) of b
 VADD.I32 Q0, Q1, Q2         @q0(0:31)=1st element of a + 1st element of b ... till 4 element
```

now how to interconnect between them? there must be some syntax for arm assembly..i dnt know that. please share some good reading. 
Note: please don't check logic & don't suggest intrinsic method

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the [Procedure Call Standard](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042f/IHI0042F_aapcs.pdf).

Then you need to link some identifiers to let C know where to find `addArr()`.
In the assembler you need `EXPORT  addArr`, and in C you will need a declaration like `__asm void addArr()`
*This depends on your toolchain.*